# How to call a sparks library from within a code igniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a library in CodeIgniter and would like to call a function that exists on the curl sparks library. How can I make a call to the function from within my library?

I have tried

```
$this->load->spark('curl/2.1.2');
$this->curl->simple_get('url');
```

doesn't seem to be working.

I have also tried

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->spark('curl/1.2.1');
$this->curl->simple_get('url');
```

This also doesn't seem to work. Can you please advice on how I can achieve this?

I use the curl sparks library http://getsparks.org/packages/curl/versions/HEAD/show

**Edit:** This question is not in relation to [Codeigniter: Consume RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115849/codeigniter-consume-restful-service) as this mostly deals with how to call a method on a Spark Library from within a standalone Code Igniter library

Comment: have add added the required extended Loader class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: Consume RESTful service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115849/codeigniter-consume-restful-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. We would have to use it as below

```
$this->CI->load->spark('library');
$this->CI->library->function();
```

This works correctly.

Comment: this doesn't work for me just yet. Is there a loader library I have to load—as specified above? I have a User class and I am trying to _lazy load_ a spark in it. But `$this->CI` returns an error `Undefined property: Users::$CI`

Answer (score 0):

in autoload.php, add

```
$autoload['sparks'] = array('library/version');
```